# EJB 3.1 - Set stateful timeout for all beans

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

Ok simple question, how do I set the timeout for all EJB 3.1 stateful beans in JBoss AS7?

I have tried various combinations in ejb-jar.xml such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <enterprise-beans>
      <session>
          <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
          <session-type>Stateful</session-type>
          <stateful-timeout>
               <timeout>61</timeout><!--Default unit is minutes -->
          </stateful-timeout>           
      </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

which produces the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011084: componentClassName is null
```

I know I can set the `Access-Timeout` in standalone.xml

I also know I can use the `@StatefulTimeout` on each bean, but I am looking for a global default, surprisingly I cannot see this documented anywhere

Comment: Why not use standalone.xml?

Comment: because Access-Timeout and Stateful-Timeout are not the same thing (unless I am mistaken?)

Comment: I think it's the same thing. In standalone.xml there is tag as:
<stateful default-access-timeout = "5000" cache-ref = "simple" />.

Note the name "access-timeout". The value is set in milliseconds.

Comment: No the docs state for Access-Timeout - 'This attribute specifies the default time concurrent invocations on the same bean instance will wait to acquire the instance lock' - I want to set the timeout for when the SFSB is destroyed after being inactive for X time

Comment: Oh @DaveB now I understand your problem. I was just thinking that you needed timeout to get a bean, not to be destroyed. Well, facing not know how to do but I'll try to find something.

Comment: thanks, tbh I dont think it exists as its not documented anywhere

Comment: Do you happen to know hat JBAS011084 actually means and how it can be debugged? I encountered it in a different situation.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Hello, me from the Past. JBAS011084 means that JBoss can't find the ejb you are referencing. Most likely you have a typo in ejb-name / annotations on the Bean itself or something like it.